# Do we need drivers for our optical drive(DVD-RAM)

Tags: dvd

When I insert a DVD-RAM disk my drive detects it as a blank CD.

Do we need drivers for our optical drive(DVD-RAM)?

Comment: you need drivers for all hardware.  As Ignacio pointed out your OS typically provided common drivers (like those for an optical drive).  What OS are you using and what is the make and model of your optical drive?  Are you sure it supports DVD-RAM?

Comment: @typoknig I've had similar problem with a BD-ROM drive that supports DVD-RAM. After formatting a disk, it cannot be read and sometimes is displayed as a DVD-R. I thought that disks were dead, but then I used another DVD-RAM drive and they worked fine on it.

Answer (score 4):

Of course. Do you need *special* drivers beyond what the OS provides? Usually no.

Comment: Can this (no-driver) be the reason for strange behaviour of my dvd-ram i.e it functions correctly with cd but when I insert a dvd it shows it as a blank cd even though dvd has data on it.

Comment: Probably the disk is just dirty or something. My drive does this as well when a dirty disk is inserted, when I clean the disk, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Geeklab No Sir, the disc works perfectly on mac, and i have got 20-25 such discs all of which show as blank disc while working perfectly in mac.

Answer (score 1):

About the question topic: Yes you need, but in 99% OS will do it for you and it does not need you to explicitly insert a driver or something.
About the problem you have: It has different reasons. 1- DVD or CD burned bad due to bad writer or bad Empty CD or DVD.
2- Reader's optical head needs cleaning.
3- Reader's Head has been damaged.